# Overriding CSS property. !important doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have to update an old page used internally only, that has the following CSS:

```css
table {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
} 

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0 25px 0 25px;
}
```

I added this table:

```
<div id="tbl_secFilter">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_pd" value="true"> Past days</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="days"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_tf" value="true"> Timeframe</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="from" class="hasDatepicker">&nbsp;to&nbsp;<input type="text" id="to" class="hasDatepicker"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_un" value="true"> Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="username"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```css
#tbl_secFilter table { border-style: none !important; }
```

But the table still has borders. Is there any workaround besides creating a class for the previous "table" CSS property? Maybe a *CSS table*?

I just wanted to align the form elements

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsk53/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just disables the border of the table itself not of the children. Use something like this instead:

```
#tbl_secFilter table,
#tbl_secFilter table td,
#tbl_secFilter table th  {
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

If you use this you can remove `!important`

Answer (score 4):

The `table` doesn't have a border, but *all of your `td`s do*. If you don't want borders around your columns, then remove the definitions from the CSS (or override them).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `border` from the `td` and the `table`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Lsk53/1/)

```css
#tbl_secFilter table td, #tbl_secFilter table {
    border: none;
}
```

No need for `!important`, just place this styling below the initial declaration to ensure that it overwrites the initial styling.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it as shown below. It was important to add `table td`. **`td`s have borders.**

```css
#tbl_secFilter table td { border: 0px solid black !important; }
```

Moreover, you don't need the `!important` anymore, so this works as well.

```css
#tbl_secFilter table td { border: 0px solid black; }
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsk53/2/

[image]

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for the downvote? Stackoverflow has a problem of people downvoting, without providing any constructive reasons for doing so. This is not improving the community at all. It's a joke.